# finding the residue of trig functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having trouble finding the residue at z=0 of the following:

> $$f(z)=\frac{\cot(z)\coth(z)}{z^3}$$
>
> I had rewritten the problem as so $$f(z)=\frac{\cot(z)\coth(z)}{(z-0)^3}$$
> so when plugging into $$\lim_{z \rightarrow a} \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}[(z-a)^{n}f(z)]$$
> I set a=0 and n=3 and reduced it down to
>
> $$\lim_{z \rightarrow a} \frac{d^{2}}{dz^{2}}[\cot(z)\coth(z)]=\lim_{z \rightarrow a} \frac{d^{2}}{dz^{2}}[\frac{i(e^{iz^{2}}+e^{-iz^{2}})}{e^{iz^{2}}-e^{-iz^{2}}}]=DNE$$

Are my a and my n wrong or are my computations wrong?

Comment: Formatting tip: your posts will look nicer and be easier to read if you use `\log`, `\sin` etc, for common functions.  Your formula looks right, so your calculations must be wrong.  I'll work through them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't computed the order of the pole correctly.
$$\frac{\cot z\coth z}{z^3}=\frac{\cos z\cosh z}{z^3\sin z\sinh z}$$
The numerator has the value $1$ at $z=0$, and both $\sin z$ and $\sinh z$ have simple zeros there.  The order of the pole is not $3$, but $5$.

**EDIT**

I should point out that using the formula is probably not the easiest way to compute the residue.  It's probably easier to compute the Laurent series.  Since the residue is the coefficient of the $\frac1z$ term in the Laurent series, and we will be dividing by $z^3$, we need to compute the series of the numerator up through terms of degree $2$.

We know that $$\cos z = 1-\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^4}{24}+\cdots\tag1$$ and $$\sin z=z-\frac{z^3}6+\frac{z^5}{120}+\cdots\tag2$$
Dividing $(1)$ by $(2)$ with long division gives
$$\cot z = \frac1z-\frac z3-\frac{z^3}{45}+O(z^5)\tag3$$
We know that $\cosh z = \cos iz$ and $\sinh z = -i \sin iz$ so that $\coth z = i\cot iz$. Applying this to $(3)$ gives $$\coth z = \frac 1z +\frac z3 -\frac {z^3}{45}+O(z^5)\tag4$$
Now, multiplying $(3)$ by $(4)$ the coefficient of the $z^2$ term will be $$-\frac19-\frac1{45}-\frac1{45}=\boxed{-\frac7{45}},$$ the resiue we seek.